# how to kill inner threads in spring boot application

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, rest, java.util.concurrent

On the Springboot-based application, I am creating a thread to finish a batch job and returning back immediately. Now, I need to forcefully kill the thread in some scenarios like a timeout.

Can anyone help me to fix this use case?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java's `Executors` Framework, you can simply use `shutDown()` method.

Otherwise, you can send an interrupt signal using `Thread.interrupt()` after your task is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Javamelody](https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki) monitoring tool integrated in your application which provides you a nice dashboard of all the current running thread and a kill button to terminate the thread. This tool is extremely easy to integrate in Spring Boot applications - you just need to include couple of dependencies in your build file. Also you would like to protect the dashboard endpoint with some authentication - javamelody provides you with basic auth feature as well.

Another DIY way is to create an endpoint in your application to return thread id for the batch process ( you would need to give some meaningful name to tth thread group to differentiate it from other threads) and another endpoint which takes in thread id as parameter and can stop/kill the thread.

[image]